# Select div by ID and copy contents in js

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I am making a simple markdown editor, I would like a button on the right hand side to copy the output. 
I can't see why the code below wouldn't be working, I have tried  a number of variations as well
as a few other methods.

Any idea how to get the second button working? The copyMD one works fine.

JS

```
function copyMD() {
    document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
        document.querySelector("textarea").select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    };
}
function copyOP() {
    document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("output").select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
    };
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="markdown-editor">
    <div class="markdown-editor_left-panel">
        <textarea bind:value={source} name="source" class="markdown-editor_source"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="markdown-editor_right-panel">
        <div class="markdown-editor_output" id="output">{@html markdown}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn" on:click={copyMD}>Copy Markdown</button>
    <button class="btn" id="btn2" on:click={copyOP}>Copy Output</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit - but the below might help you. Run the code snippet.

Note, I changed how the callback is called in the html. You might want to change this back for svelte.

#### Update: what was wrong with your code

The callback you attached to the buttons, was itself attaching a callback to the buttons. I don't know much about svelte, but i know this: in your callbacks, you get reference to a button and then attach a callback. That seems wrong. You should either attach the callback in javascript outside of any function calls, so it is attached when the javascript script laods, or you attach it in the html - this is a nicer option and what I have done here. Again, in the callbacks you attached to your html buttons, you were attaching a callback to the buttons. Does that make sense?

```js
function copyMD(){
     document.querySelector("textarea").select();
     document.execCommand('copy');
}
function copyOP(){
// apparently select only works for text area and docment.execCommand I think it deprecated.
    const output = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
// the navigator object in a browser holds lots of useful utilities, such as location services and clipboard interface.
    const theClipboard = navigator.clipboard;
// write text returns a promise, so use `then` to react to success
    theClipboard.writeText(output).then(() => console.log('copied to clipboard'));
}
```

```html
<div class="markdown-editor">
    <div class="markdown-editor_left-panel">
        <textarea bind:value={source} name="source" class="markdown-editor_source"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="markdown-editor_right-panel">
        <div class="markdown-editor_output" id="output">{@html markdown}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
    <!-- I change this to onclick so it would work in stack overflow, perhaps you can put this back to svelte syntax -->
    <button class="btn" onclick="copyMD()">Copy Markdown</button>
    <!-- I change this to onclick so it would work in stack overflow, perhaps you can put this back to svelte syntax -->
    <button class="btn" id="btn2" onclick="copyOP()">Copy Output</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what you changed in the javascript and why.

Comment: @Sean, good feedback - i have made an effort - anything that could be clearer?

Comment: The major thing to address would be the need to use `.innerHTML()` instead of `.execCommand('copy')`

Answer (score 0):

[.select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) will only work on a textarea. You could use innerHTML on the div element to get its contents